# Using Collection_select to display a list of names based on current user

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine

Hi guys I am new to Ruby and was wondering if there was a way I could use collection select in order to provide the user a list of other users that share the same business_id as them.

At the moment my collection_select allows selection of every user in the database:

```
<%= f.collection_select :id, Customer.all, :id, :full_name, :prompt => 'Select' %>
```

I was wondering if I could do something like

```
<%= f.collection_select :id, User.find_by_business_id(current_user.business_id), ... %>
```

but this does not work.

current_user is a method defined in applications_controller to find the current user that is logged in.

Please help as I'm very new to rails and could not find a solution! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you would need to do is create a query to get the list of users who share a business_id with the current user. Instead of:

```
<%= f.collection_select :id, User.all, :id, :full_name, :prompt => 'Select' %>
```

You want to replace the `User.all` with a subset of users. Assuming the field is called business_id in both the users table and in the current_user, this is probably what you want:

```
<%= f.collection_select :id, User.where(business_id: current_user.business_id), :id, :full_name, :prompt => 'Select' %>
```

What the line `User.where(business_id: current_user.business_id)` is doing is giving a collection of users whose business_id column contains a certain value (in this case the same value as the current_user).

If you're not especially familiar with .where() or the Active Record Query Interface, I would strongly encourage you to read over [this documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) at your leisure.

**Addendum:**

In response to your most recent update to the question, you do not want to use the `.find_by_business_id()` method. This will only return a single result (the first record to match its criteria.

Comment: sorry, wherever I put Customer, I meant User! You have fixed it and I will read the documentation thank you